# Twilio send an sms

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

Hello I have to verify the user phone numbers in my app. I have implemented twilio library but I am unable to send an sms. I am getting this error

```
Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The From phone number +120xxxxxxx is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account
```

I haven't bought their subscription yet. I want to first test their service so I am using trial account. I have used test `AccountSID` and  Test `authToken` .

```
<?php

require "twilio/Services/Twilio.php";

// set your AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
 $AccountSid = "testaccountsid";
    $AuthToken = "testauthtoken";

    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    $message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
        "From" => "+1xxxxxxxx",
        "To" => "+92xxxxxxx",
        "Body" => "Test message!",
    ));

// Display a confirmation message on the screen
echo "Sent message {$message->sid}";
```

**From:** when I clicked `Get your first twilio phone number` they given me one US mobile number which I used in From field

[image]

**To:** Here I have used my own number so that I can receive the text. My own number was used in twilio also for verification purposes

I basically want to use twilio to send random pin code from a number like "6323" or something like this. Please tell me what I am missing. And also they are giving me US number which I used in From field. How can I get the short number like "6323" or a alphabetical name like "whatsapp" in From field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21606):

> **Test Credentials**
>
> If you received this error while trying to authenticate with your Test Credentials, you probably tried to send a message with a From number from your live account. The only number that can be used to send successful messages with your Test Credentials is +15005550006. For more information, read our documentation on the From number for sending SMS with your test credentials.

So you need to hardcode `+15005550006` as `From`.

For even more info on their API, see [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#test-sms-messages-parameters-From)

Comment: This is absolutely correct. Just to add to it, when you haven't yet upgraded your account with a credit card, you can send SMS messages to your own phone number using the Live Credentials and it won't cost you anything either.

Comment: @AlexTartan thanks alex for the answer. Okay Its working now and it says sent message. But I am not receiving any sms on my mobile.